# Map a single property from a relationship using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to map a one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework, where the "many" side of the relationship is actually just a simple type?

As an example, let's say these are my database tables:

```
create table EventDetails 
(
    EventId int not null identity(1, 1),
    Name nvarchar(200) not null,

    constraint PK_EVentDetails primary key (EventId)
)

create table EventDates 
(
    EventId int not null,
    EventDate date not null,

    constraint PK_EventDates primary key (EventId, EventDate),
    constraint FK_EventDate_Event foreign key (EventId) references EventDetails(EventId)
)
```

I'd like to represent this as a class, as follows:

```
public class EventDetails {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }
}
```

Just not sure how I can do this using an entity map:

```
public class EventDetailsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EventDetails>
{
    public EventDetailsMap()
    {
        ToTable("EventDetails").HasKey(evnt => evnt.Id);

        // --- WHAT GOES HERE?? ---
        HasMany(evnt => evnt.Dates)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(/* ??? */);
    }
}
```

My gut feeling is that I can't do this - instead, I have to create an `EventDate` class - but would be nice to know for sure!

(For reference: I'm using EF6)

Comment: Pretty sure you need a full entity otherwise EF doesn't know how to map to a database table.

Comment: I would agree with @DavidG in the sense that you're not telling EF that `Dates` is a `DbSet` (or a navigation property). Rather, you're just telling EF that your Model has a list of `DateTimes` (which is incorrect - it is another table/entity). I will say that it probably is possible (since EF is open source) to create a custom configuration, but I imagine it is a nice chunk of work.